# Redirecionamento não interrompe interpretação do script?

Tags: php, lógica, redirecionamento

Pode-me estar a escapar algo, mas de maneira nenhuma consigo ver o quê. Eu tenho um código simples de login que se está a comportar (pelo menos é o que me parece) de forma estranha.

index.php:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['error'];
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
    username
    <input type="text" name="username">
    password
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

process.php

```
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if($_POST['password'] == 'password' && $_POST['username'] == 'miguel') {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Loggedin Success';
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Wrong details (username/password)';
    header('Location: index.php');
}
$_SESSION['error'] = 'NO POST REQUEST';
header('Location: index.php');
```

Ora bem, o que se está a passar com este código é que quer eu coloque as credências erradas ou certas (miguel/password) ele vai interpretar sempre o ultimo bloco

```
$_SESSION['error'] = 'NO POST REQUEST';
header('Location: index.php');
```

Como é que isso é possível? Visto que passamos por redirecionamentos antes, a interpretação do script (process.php) não deveria ter sido interrompida/cancelada nesse momento e redirecionar-nos para o destino?

Se colocar `elses` contendo os blocos o código já faz o "suposto":

```
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if($_POST['password'] == 'password' && $_POST['username'] == 'miguel') {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Mas porque são eles necessários nesta estrutura? Sempre pensei que ao interpretar um `header('Location: ...');` a interpretação do próprio script seria interrompida

Comment: A função header apenas envia o header, você precisa de um exit após a chamada. Como você está mandando vários headers iguais em sequência, o browser está considerando o último.

Comment: Haa @bfavaretto. Sempre pensei que o redirecionamento ocorria nesse momento. Percebi, sei que a pergunta parece estupida e peço desculpa, mas estava-me a fazer imensa confusão isto. Podes colocar uma boa resposta que eu aceito... Já percebi o que se passa então, colocando um `die();` a seguir aos headers já resulta portanto

Comment: Isso, o die() também funciona. Não vou deixar resposta agora porque estou no mobile, talvez mais tarde.

Comment: Ok @bfavaretto , fica descansado que aceitarei a tua (se for boa (: ), visto que foste o primeiro que me esclareceu/resolveu a minha dúvida

Comment: Se aparecer uma resposta boa antes, pode aceitar se quiser :) Não achei a pergunta estúpida, esse comportamento não é óbvio mesmo.

Comment: @bfavaretto , então a minha resposta :P ?

Comment: Demorou, mas chegou : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função [`header`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) do PHP apenas envia um cabeçalho HTTP ao browser, e o protocolo HTTP permite vários header por requisição ou resposta. Portanto o PHP não sabe que você está fazendo um redirecionamento, ele acrescenta todos os headers e cabe ao user-agent que fez a requisição (browser, normalmente) decidir o que fazer. No caso ele está decidindo por redirecionar para o último cabeçalho `Location:` encontrado. Isso deve ser padrão do protocolo (mas não tenho fontes para confirmar, se alguém souber pode comentar ou editar minha resposta).

Portanto, você precisa colocar um [`exit` ou `die`](http://php.net/exit) após enviar o cabeçalho `Location:`, para que o PHP não execute o código que envia os seguintes:

```
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if($_POST['password'] == 'password' && $_POST['username'] == 'miguel') {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Loggedin Success';
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Wrong details (username/password)';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
$_SESSION['error'] = 'NO POST REQUEST';
header('Location: index.php');
// aqui não precisa de exit pois é o último
```

Comment: Sim, percebi, e acho que esse header (tal como todos os outros) só é efetivamente executado quando a interpretação do script, neste caso php, termina. Obagdo pelo esclarecimento